# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Tags: python, directory, filenames, subdirectory

I am trying to access a given folder, then access all of its sub folders (20+), and then access the only `xlsx` file inside of each sub folder to do some calculations.

My code is using `load_workbook` from `openpyxl`. I need a for loop to read the existing files within the same folder, but these files change their name from sub folder to sub folder. To workaround the fact that `load_workbook` takes the precise name of the `xlsx` file as input, I opted for this solution:

```
filename=os.path.basename(file)
wb=load_workbook(filename)
```

but it raises this error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'endswith'`. **How to workaround my workaround?**

My complete script:

```
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook

directoryPath=r'C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\MyFolder'
os.chdir(directoryPath)
folder_list=os.listdir(directoryPath)
for folders, sub_folders, file in os.walk(directoryPath):
    for name in file:
        if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
            filename=os.path.basename(file) #This is supposed to dump the name of the current file to a variable to be used by load_workbook
            wb=load_workbook(filename)
            cell_range = wb['A1':'A10'] #Accessing some cells

            #some calculations
```

Comment: You just used the wrong variable in `if file.endswith(".xlsx"):` .... use `name` instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change

`if file.endswith(".xlsx"):`

to

`if name.endswith(".xlsx"):`